# JSF param not passing in <h:button> onclick

Tags: jsf-2

View param does not get passed to a popUp window from JSF hbutton

```
<h:button id="popup" onclick="javascript: void window.open('#{request.contextPath}/pages/index.xhtml', 'popUpWindow', windowfeatures);" value="Button">
<f:param name="id" value="#{showBean1.id}"/>
</h:button>
```

I have on the popUp page the receiving view in the right place above the header

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="id" 
        value="#{bean2.pro}" 
        converter="#{productionconverter}" 
        converterMessage="Unknown value, please use a link from within the system."
        required="true" 
        requiredMessage="Bad request, please use a link from within the system."/>

</f:metadata>
```

The page opens in the popup window but there is no param passed in the popUp page address and nothing shows up on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's to be expected isn't it? You're doing something that's strictly a client-side operation, you can't expect something that's essentially a server-side component to be involved in the production of the outcome. The `NavigationHandler` evaluates all navigation requests; in your case, it doesn't get a chance to process the navigation request (because `onclick`), so none of that JSF goodness kicks in.

You should try plainly including the value that you're expecting as part of the target URL

```
<h:button id="popup" onclick="javascript: void window.open('#{request.contextPath}/pages/index.xhtml?id=#{showBean1.id}', 'popUpWindow', windowfeatures);" value="Button"/>
```

Comment: works like magic.. Thought of it but didn't know how to. Guess I have to be more experimental with JSF.. 7weeks and counting and I'm getting better. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome @ollaollu. And yes, you should feel free to try stuff, with almost any piece of tech